# Creating an array with awk and passing it to a second awk operation

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a column file and I want to print all the lines that do not contain the string SOL, and to print only the lines that do contain SOL but has the 5th column <1.2 or >4.8.

The file is structured as: MOLECULENAME ATOMNAME X Y Z

Example:

```
  151SOL     OW 6554   5.160   2.323   4.956  
  151SOL    HW1 6555   5.188   2.254   4.690  ----> as you can see this atom is out of the   
  151SOL    HW2 6556   5.115   2.279   5.034  threshold, but it need to be printed
```

What I thought is to save a vector with all the MOLECULENAME that I want, and then tell awk to match all the MOLECULENAME saved in vector "a" with the file, and print the complete output. ( if I only do the first awk i end up having bad atom linkage near the thershold)

The problem is that i have to pass the vector from the first awk to the second... I tried like this with a[], but of course it doesn't work.

How can i do this ?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
a[] = (awk 'BEGIN{i=0} $1 !~ /SOL/{a[i]=$1;i++}; /SOL/ && $5 > 4.8 {a[i]=$1;i++};/SOL/ &&$5<1.2 {a[i]=$1;i++}')

awk -v a="$a[$i]" 'BEGIN{i=0} $1 ~ $a[i] {if (NR>6540) {for (j=0;j<3;j++) {print $0}} else {print $0}
```

Comment: Why not combine the two two commands to a single awk?

Comment: How? If the atom in the threshold is not the first of the molecule i can't tell awk to go back and read the preceiding lines..

Comment: From your sample : `151SOL OW 6554 5.160 2.323 4.956` it seems that 4.956 is in the sixth column not the fifth, as you say. Also: what is the purpose of `NR>6540`?

Comment: awk is not shell, just like C (or whatever your favorite programming languages is) is not shell. It is a separate tool. How would you pass an array created in one C program to another C program? The awk solution would be the same as that. Having said that - as others have pointed out it's highly unlikely you'd actually need to do that but post some expected output from your sample input so we can help you more. Oh and stop talking about atoms as we don't know or care about any of the domain-specific stuff - just tell us about the strings and their positions in your input and output.

Comment: @HåkonHægland that's another problem, when the 3rd field get past 10000 the 2nd and 3d field become one,i solved the problem posted, now i only have to split the colums.

Answer (score 1):

You can put all of the same molecule names in one row by using sort on the file and then running this AWK which basically uses printf to print on the same line until a different molecule name is found. Then, a new line starts. The second AWK script is used to detect which molecules names have  3 valid lines in the original file. I hope this can help you to solve your problem

```
sort your_file | awk 'BEGIN{ molname=""; } ( $0 !~ "SOL" || ( $0 ~ "SOL" && ( $5<1.2 || $5>4.8 ) )  ){ if($1!=molname){printf("\n");molname=$1}for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf("%s ",$i);}}' | awk 'NF>12 {print $0}'
```

Comment: I wasn't clear enough sorry, but i can't do it in a single line, because there are some molecules for which one atom is inside the thershold but the hydrogen bonded to it isn't, and i can't lose atom as that, i need all the atoms. 
EX:   
SOLV1 O x y 4.7                                                      
SOLV1 H x y 4.9 ---> in, so all the molecule have to be in             
SOLV1 H x y 4.7                                              
(i don't understand how to add a newline in the comment, i tried with the doublespace but it doesn't work)

Comment: How many items with the same MOLECULENAME can appear in the document?

Comment: For the solvent moleculetype, which is the one of interest, 3.

Comment: Check the new solution please, it may help you

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '!/SOL/ || $5 < 1.2 || $5 > 4.8' inputfile.txt
```

Print (default behaviour) lines where:

- "SOL" is not found
- SOL is found and fifth column < 1.2
- SOL is found and fifth column > 4.8

Comment: Mmmm will this print when `SOL` is found and `$5 < 1.2`?

Comment: I wasn't clear enough sorry, but i can't do it in a single line, because there are some molecules for which one atom is inside the thershold but the hydrogen bonded to it isn't, and i can't lose atom as that, i need all the atoms.

EX: SOLV1 O x y 4.7  
    SOLV1 H x y 4.9 ---> in, so all the molecule have to be in  
    SOLV1 H x y 4.7

Comment: @fedorqui - yes, have tested. OP - can you add this requirement to your question? Ideally, add some sample input data as well.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! Thanks to all, here is how i solved it.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    file=$1
    awk 'BEGIN {molecola="";i=0;j=1;}  
    {if ($1 !~ /SOL/) {print $0}    
    else if ( $1 != molecola && $1 ~ /SOL/ ) {   
    for (j in arr_comp) {if( arr_comp[j] < 1.2 || arr_comp[j] > 5) {for(j in arr_comp)                                 {print   arr_mol[j] };break}}  
    delete(arr_comp)  
    delete(arr_mol)  
    arr_mol[0]=$0   
    arr_comp[0]=$5  
    molecola=$1  
    j=1     
    }   
    else {arr_mol[j]=$0;arr_comp[j]=$5;j++} }' $file
```